# How do I start a Unity Android app via ADB?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, adb

I'm trying to figure out how to start a Unity app from ADB, ideally so I can pass custom intent parameters for automated device testing. So far, I'm stuck just on *starting* a Unity app via ADB. I am well aware that this is possible, and it *MUST* be possible because apps like Sidequest are able to accomplish this on the exact same app, on the exact same phone, that I can't make this work on.

I'm currently using an unmodified Unity Android Manifest, which I can confirm both launches normally from a Pixel 4a and can launch from Sidequest. I've tried the following commands that many people claim should work

```
 adb shell am start -n com.Futurus.AIntent/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity

 adb shell am start -n "com.Futurus.AIntent/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"

 adb -d shell am start -f 0x10000000 -n com.Futurus.AIntent/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity

 adb shell am start -n com.Futurus.AIntent/unityplayer.UnityActivity -a android.intent.action.MAIN
```

Every single command I've tried claims that the activity class does not exist, despite the fact that it matches what's in the compiled manifest that I looked at in Android Studio. If I try to `resolve-activity` I get `No activity found` which seems like it cannot possibly be true because the app runs when opened via tap or Sidequest.

I'm a complete loss, below I've copy-pasted the analyzed manifest from Android Studio. As best as I can tell, I'm performing the start command correctly but for the life of me it will not open. Any help is greatly appreciated

I'm using Unity 2021.3.4f1 on Win11, ADB through Powershell if any of that matters.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.1"
    android:installLocation="2"
    android:compileSdkVersion="30"
    android:compileSdkVersionCodename="11"
    package="com.Futurus.AIntentTest"
    platformBuildVersionCode="30"
    platformBuildVersionName="11">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="22"
        android:targetSdkVersion="30" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x30000" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.vulkan.version"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:label="@ref/0x7f030005"
        android:icon="@ref/0x7f020000"
        android:extractNativeLibs="true">

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f040001"
            android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
            android:launchMode="2"
            android:screenOrientation="10"
            android:configChanges="0x40003fff"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:resizeableActivity="false">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity"
                android:value="true" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.notch_support"
                android:value="true" />
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.splash-mode"
            android:value="0" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.splash-enable"
            android:value="true" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.launch-fullscreen"
            android:value="true" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.allow-resizable-window"
            android:value="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="notch.config"
            android:value="portrait|landscape" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Your package is `com.Futurus.AIntentTest` but the commands you have tried do not include the "Test" part - have you tried `adb shell am start -n com.Futurus.AIntentTest/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity`?

Comment: I've been a complete fool, thank you that worked

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything right, nice tutorial. Just the thing I was looking for!

As per Luke's comment:

> our package is com.Futurus.AIntentTest but the commands you have tried do not include the "Test" part - have you tried adb shell am start -n com.Futurus.AIntentTest/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity?

Problem was just a small issue with class names.

I added this as an answer, for making the solution more visible. If luke adds his own answer here; I will happily delete this one.